# String Manipulation To Get An Item In The Middle Of A CSV File

Tags: vb.net

I have a csv file I need to parse and get an item out of the middle of it. I have chose string manipulation to do this.

sample input file data would be..

```
Nick,frog,snake,1234
```

I can get the last entry "1234" with this code..

```
 line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(",") + 1)
```

How would I get the 3rd entry, "snake", with substrings? (what the OP means is: how can I get the third element in the comma-separated string, which happens to be "snake")

Comment: I have quickly written a pretty good code (in the moment and without having attempted this problem ever before) which I had to delete (really unpleasant experience). Because of the behaviour I have seen (incompatibility of characters, nothing personal, etc. just to avoid misunderstandings), I will not help you further. But, please try to learn from this experience and make from SO (and the world) a better place: 1. Be CLEAR (write proper English, with proper punctuation and explain as much as possible); 2. In case of seeing a misunderstanding, please, please, ASK, inquire, start a discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've stored the text of your file in `myInputText`, and you want to access the third item, the following will work:

`resultString = Strings.Split(myInputText, ",")(2)`

You can access any string in the file this way.

Comment: I understood the OP perfectly. I would also love to see a source saying the Strings module is deprecated. The [4.5 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) makes no mention of this. My experience with you on this site has been brief, but I've arrived at the conclusion that you are simply delusional. Editing an answer from someone you apparently have a vendetta with is counter-productive.

Comment: NOTE FOR FUTURE READERS: Strings.Split refers to the old VB Split function (VB6, before .NET). The .NET equivalent is string.Split (givenString.Split(","c), as shown by tinstaafl). In this specific case, there is no solid reason to prefer one method over the other; on the hand, there are quite a few of these old functions which might be confusing because of following different indexing systems; even the fact of having duplicated, similar functions (Strings.Split and string.Split) behaving differently is something which seems better to avoid.

Comment: NOTE FOR HELRICH: I have already explained you the reasons for my behaviour: I didn't like your attitude in the other post and the weird situation in this one hasn't helped. The solution is pretty easy: same one than for Nick LaMarca, better don't expect help (or anything else) from me.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I get the 3rd entry "snake" with substrings?

The easiest way would obviously be with split:

```
    Dim teststr As String = "Nick,frog,snake,1234"
    Dim teststr2 As String = teststr.Split(","c)(2)
```

A simple function like this, using substring, will do the same thing:

```
    Dim teststr3 As String = GetStr(teststr, 2)


Private Function GetStr(input As String, index As Integer) As String
    input += ","
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    If index <> 0 Then
        Do
            input = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(","c)).TrimStart(","c)
            counter += 1
        Loop Until counter = index
    End If

    GetStr = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(","c))
End Function
```